# Why isn't this AngularJS populating my dropdown?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, json

Here is my select:

```
<select class="dropdownInForm" ng-model="vehicle">
    <option ng-repeat="vehicle in vehicles" value="vehicle.VehicleID">{{vehicle.VehicleName}}</option>
</select>
```

Here is how I am loading the data in my angular controller:

```
$http.post('VehicleEdit.aspx/GetVehicles', { vendorID: $scope.vendorID, placeID: $scope.placeID})
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.vehicles = response.data;
                $scope.vehicle = $scope.vehicles[0];
            })
```

And here is what response.data contains:

```
"[{"VehicleID":1,"VehicleName":"test1","IsActive":false},{"VehicleID":1,"VehicleName":"test2","IsProgrammatic":true}]"
```

The pull from the database is working as I am debugging it in Chrome and can see that $scope.vehicles is populated with the above JSON. However, this dropdown will not populate no matter what I try.

Where am I going wrong?

EDIT --

I should have noted that I did try it this way as well, without any luck:

```
<select class="dropdownInForm" ng-model="vehicle" ng-options="vehicle.VehicleId as vehicle.VehicleName for vehicle in vehicles"></select>
```

Here is the WebMethod that retuns the JSON:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetVehicles(int placeID, int vendorID)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        DataSet vehiclesData = VehicleLogic.GetListOfVehicles(placeID, vendorID);

        List<Vehicle> vehicles = new List<Vehicle>();

        foreach(DataRow row in vehiclesData.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle()
            {
                VehicleID = Convert.ToInt32(row["VehicleID"]),
                VehicleName = row["VehicleName"].ToString().Trim(),
                IsProgrammatic = Convert.ToBoolean(row["IsProgrammatic"])
            };

            vehicles.Add(vehicle);
        }

        return jsonSerializer.Serialize(vehicles);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using ng-options

```
<select ng-model="vehicle" ng-options="k as k.VehicleName for k in vehicles" >
</select>
```

Comment: I did try this way as well, no luck. I edited my post to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.vehicles = [{
      "VehicleID": 1,
      "VehicleName": "test1",
      "IsActive": false
    }, {
      "VehicleID": 1,
      "VehicleName": "test2",
      "IsProgrammatic": true
    }];
    $scope.vehicle = $scope.vehicles[0];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <select ng-model="vehicle" ng-options="vehicle as vehicle.VehicleName for vehicle in vehicles"></select>
  <div>
    Selected Vehicle: {{vehicle | json}}
  </div>
</div>
```

`value` is not an Angular directive so you have to use `{{vehicle.VehicleID}}` when setting the `value` for your `<option>` elements. However, a much better approach would be to use `ng-options`:

```
<select class="dropdownInForm" ng-model="vehicle" ng-options="vehicle.VehicleID as vehicle.VehicleName for vehicle in vehicles"></select>
```

Comment: I did try this way as well, no luck. I edited my post to reflect this.

Comment: I can assure you that this method should work, as demonstrated by the code snippet I just added to my answer. If it is not working for you then there is an error somewhere else in code which you have not shown us.

Comment: Ah...I see what you are doing. You have set `$scope.vehicle` to one of the elements of your `$scope.vehicles` array, thereby making it an object. However, the value in the select which you were trying to assign is `VehicleID` which is a number. I have updated the code to reflect this and to demonstrate that it still works properly.

Comment: Still not working.. Could it be something wrong with the JSON? I added the WebMethod that returns the JSON above.

Comment: Hmm, probably. Why are not using WebApi for your server-side code? WebMethods are notorious for not dealing well with JSON. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23298754/548997) for more info.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's an old system and it's all webforms. I would much rather use WebApi..

Answer (score 0):

try to not use same var name for ng-model=vehicle"  and ng-repeat="vehicle as ...